# PowerBI DAX: How to calculate a running total for both date and another filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate a running total of a measure by date and by source. Below is a screenshot how my table looks like now.

[image: Measure by date and by source]

Below is the measure code.

```
CashPosition_Revenue Running Total = CALCULATE([CashPosition_Revenue],FILTER(VALUES(FilterKeys_Date[Date]), FilterKeys_Date[Date] <= MAX(FilterKeys_Date[Date])))
```

I need last column to be calculated as running total.

Comment: can I ask what result to do you expect, what is your running total formula or logic?

Comment: I expect to see every row should be the sum of all above rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using Values limits your filter context to the current date only, try using All to remove that filter:

```
CashPosition_Revenue Running Total = 
    VAR CurrentDate = MAX(FilterKeys_Date[Date])
   RETURN 
   CALCULATE(
        SUM(FilterKeys_Date[CashPosition_Revenue]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('FilterKeys_Date'),
            FilterKeys_Date[Date] <= CurrentDate
            )
        )
```

Comment: It has not returned any values. I tried to use ALLSELECTED instead of ALL, it returns data related to first month.

Comment: I've edited to hard code the sum of values rather than using your measure name, it's possible there was something n that causing the issue. I've assumed the raw field name is the same as the measure name.